# Edit table row with jquery and twig

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twig

I have table in my twig template generated dynamically:

```
{% for a in abc %}
   <tr>
      <td>
          {{ a.key }}
      </td>
    <td>
         {{ a.value }}
    </td>
    <td class="td-actions">
        <button id='EditSave' data-text="Save" data-id="{{ a.id }}">Edit</button>
        <button id='Cancel' data-text="Cancel" style="display:none;">Cancel</button>
    </td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I made my js function that will change attribute on click.

I am new in js and what I want to accomplish further is that on specific row 'Edit' click these two field become editable.

I know how to implement ajax but don't know how to access is with twig and jquery.

My func:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//getting id of specific column
var id = $(this).data('id');

$("#EditSave").click(function(){
    var btnText = $(this).text();
    if(btnText === 'Edit')
    {
        $(this).text('Save');
        $('#Cancel').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).text('Edit');
        $('#Cancel').hide();
    }
});

$('#Cancel').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#EditSave').text('Edit');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `class` selector instead of `id` because here you have mutliple `trs`.Also , you can change your html like below :

```
{% for a in abc %}
       <tr>
          <td>
 <!--added here span and input with values-->
             <span> {{ a.key }}</span><input type="text" class="key" value="{{ a.key }}">
          </td>
        <td>
             <span>{{ a.value }}</span><input type="text" class="value" value="{{ a.value }}">
        </td>
        <td class="td-actions">
<!-- change here class-->
            <button class='EditSave' data-text="Save" data-id="{{ a.id }}">Edit</button>
            <button class='Cancel' data-text="Cancel" style="display:none;">Cancel</button>
        </td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now , onclick of `EditSave` you check use `$(this).closest("tr")` to get current row tr and hide the `spans` and show input-box and if changes made then you just need to get the values from input-boxes and set them to span and make ajax call with required datas.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mytable input").hide()//hide input from table

  $(".EditSave").click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).closest("tr")
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var btnText = $(this).text();
    if (btnText === 'Edit') {
      $(this).text('Save');
      $(this).next("button").show(); //hide
      selector.find("td span").hide() //span hide
      selector.find("td input").show() //show inputs
    } else {
      $(this).text('Edit');
      $(this).next("button").hide();
      selector.find("td span").show()
      selector.find("td input").hide()

      //get values from input box which is edited
      var key = selector.find(".key").val();
      var value = selector.find(".value").val()
      //your ajax call put here to send both value  and id as well
      //put updated values in span again add this inside success fn of ajax call
      selector.find(" td:eq(0) span").text(key) 
      selector.find(" td:eq(1) span").text(value)
    }



  });

  $('.Cancel').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev(".EditSave").text('Edit');
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td span").show()
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td input").hide()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span> A</span><input type="text" class="key" value="A">
    </td>
    <td>
      <span> B </span><input type="text" class="value" value="B">
    </td>
    <td class="td-actions">
      <button class='EditSave' data-text="Save" data-id="A">Edit</button>
      <button class='Cancel' data-text="Cancel" style="display:none;">Cancel</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>B </span><input type="text" class="key" value="B">
    </td>
    <td>
      <span> D </span><input type="text" class="value" value="D">
    </td>
    <td class="td-actions">
      <button class='EditSave' data-text="Save" data-id="D">Edit</button>
      <button class='Cancel' data-text="Cancel" style="display:none;">Cancel</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You saved me. Thank you. @Swati

Comment: Glad i helped .You can set this answer as accepted if that solve your problem :)